# Which dis(similarity) matrix to choose for proportions (over columns for each row)?

Tags: proportion, distance

I have a matrix where each row $i$ is an observation and for each observation there are several features $j$, where values $x_{ij} \in [0, 1]$.

Each row sums ups to to 1, meaning that each column $j$ for observation $i$ represents **proportion**.

**Which dis(similarity) matrix** should I use for this kind of data. My purpose is to visualize it in 2 or 3 dimensional space.

Is there any method that would capture the nature of proportion data better than Euclidian or Manhattan distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $j$ does not go too high, I see no reason not to use simple euclidean distances. The data is already scaled and all variables are of the same type (interval). As distance measures go, this is an easy case.

I'm assuming that there is no specific hierarchy among the variables. i.e. that $j=1$ does not measure something like the proportion of measures flagged "low", $j=2$ "medium" and $j=3$ "high". If that is the case, then a record with most of the proportion in high is more different from one with mostly low as it is from one with mostly medium. That would complicate things.

If your only objective is to visualize the data, I am not even sure you need to use a distance matrix. You could do a simple PCA.

Comment: There is no hierarchy among variables. I would like to narrow down the question to selecting the right metric for calculating distance metric. I pointed out the purpose to give you more context.

Comment: How many dimensions to you have then?

Comment: 20 to 50, may be even more than that. Why do you think it matters in the context of your answer?

Comment: Because euclidean distance is pretty meaningless with so many dimensions (look up curse of dimensionality, distance concentration effect). If you had 10 or less, you could have just gone with euclidean. I would probably recommend uncentered PCA (the variables are already in the same "units", standardizing them would actually distort that). Either PCA as a way to reduce dimensionality before computing an euclidean distance matrix, but you could also just do the PCA and plot the first 2 or 3 dimensions for your vizualization.